# Is asking for screen shots allowed?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I am a crossover enthusiast and try to verify crossovers as much as possible. Sometimes that entails asking for help finding screen shots from films and television series. Is that allowed here if one specific thing is wanted in the screen shots from several sources?

Example: I am looking for X in the following series: *Foo*, *Bar*, and *Baz*. Please post screen shots.

Comment: You could possibly ask "is there a situation where Foo, Bar and Baz" and sometimes people will post screenshots in support.  You can't really demand a screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No

This falls under our "off-topic/not suitable" rule of

> Locating or purchasing movie or TV content

We are not a resource for images or any other such trivia.

Such things can be easily obtained by free screen capture software yourself.

Comment: Some things are not easily obtained without the money to afford to rent entire TV series just to find a possible blink and you'll miss it moment (especially when two of the TV series are soap operas). I will continue to try to find help with this elsewhere.